# How to delete or not list my custom nuget package which is installed in my server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nuget-package

Can anyone help how to delete my custom nuget package which i have installed it in my nuget server. I used the following command to push my nugetpackage to server

NuGet push "test.1.0.0.0.nupkg" -s "server" "pwd"

or don't show those nuget packages in Manage Nuget Packages in VisualStudio.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about nuget.org, you can't. On nuget.org, you can only delist the package, but if somebody knows the id and version, it can still be pulled.

If you are talking about a self hosted nuget server, your question has been answere over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21933415/1120092